# How to validated time in PHP?

Tags: php

Hi i want to validated time between 11PM to 7AM. But not working.

Please check my code:

```
<?php
$curTime=date('G:i');
if(($curTime >= '23:00') && ($curTime <= '7:00')){
   echo "Working...";
   //some code here...
}else{
   echo "Sorry! this app not working at this time. Please use this app between 11pm to 7am <br><br>Thanks";
}
?>
```

I have checked this code after `11:00PM` but it is not working.

Please help me.

Comment: You should use unix timestamps and then generate the timestamps for 11pm and 7am every day and check whether the current timestamp is between those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$curTime=date('H');
if(($curTime >= 23) || ($curTime < 7)){
   echo "Working...";
   //some code here...
}else{
   echo "Sorry! this app not working at this time. Please use this app between 11pm to 7am <br><br>Thanks";
}
?>
```

You cannot compare strings like that. It is not logical.
Use either just the hour or: HourMin without the ':' sign.
Those you can use math one ;)

Comment: You should use `date('G');`

Comment: Yes you could however it doesn't really matter.
I like using H, if you do something else with it, it will have the leading 0 wich is cleaner on the front end:)

Comment: Hi @user3232725 your code is working fine. but when time is 7 to 8 am it also working. i need it will work between `11PM to 7AM` not `7.01 or 7.59` Please let me know how to fix that

Comment: Oops you guys are right, edited it. It should run between 7 and 23 now ;)

Answer (score 0):

- 11PM is 23 hours, not 11.
- Time can't be both greater than 11pm and less than 7am.
- You're comparing strings and not actual time.

Here's an example using DateTime() which make the logic a little bit clearer.

```
<?php
$curTime = new DateTime();
$am = new DateTime('07:00');
$pm = new DateTime('23:00');
if(($curTime < $pm) && ($curTime > $am)){
   echo "Working...";
   //some code here...
}else{
   echo "Sorry! this app not working at this time. Please use this app between 11pm to 7am <br><br>Thanks";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work from 23:00:00 - 06:59:59

```
<?php
$curTime=date('H');
if(($curTime >= 23) || ($curTime <= 6)){
   echo "Working...";
   //some code here...
}else{
   echo "Sorry! this app not working at this time. Please use this app between 11pm to 7am <br><br>Thanks";
}
?>
```

Hope, you dont need, it to work exactly at 07:00:00 ;-)